# write return value c

Tags: c, linux, posix

On a linux machine,

what are some reasons that a write() or writev() writing to a file will write less than the bytes given to it?

i know its a valid return value to return > 0 and < the size you give to the write call, but I'm curious why this should happen at all....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons listed in [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html), including:

> - If a `write()` requests that more bytes be written than there is room for (for example, the process' file size limit or  the physical end of a medium), only as many bytes as there is room for shall be written.
> - If `write()` is interrupted by a signal after it successfully writes some data, it shall return the number of bytes written.

Comment: A couple issues with this answer. 1) signals cannot interrupt unless you've setup a signal handler and failed to specify `SA_RESTART`. 2) For an ordinary file, `write` should never return a short write unless the disk is full. But for sockets, pipes, devices, there are plenty of reasons such as limited buffer size why `write` might send less than you requested. Sometimes these reasons only apply in non-blocking mode; the complete answer is complicated.

Comment: @R.:  I'd be interested in the complete answer, if you are willing to post it.  I admit, I am in no way a POSIX expert.

Comment: it was because it was running out of space. i was a little confused about free disk space, there is a distinction between superuser disk space and other users... apparently super users have more "free disk space" than other users...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the volume is out of space or the user is over quota.